# Merging cells in r

Tags: r

1. I have a matrix "a" of the following type:

   ```
   a<-matrix(c(1,"ich esse", 1, "gerne bananen", 1, "dazu auch einen apfel", 2, "ich mag brezen", 2, "mit butter"), nrow=5, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE )
   ```
2. I want to get a matrix "b" looking like this:

   ```
    b<-matrix(c(1,"ich esse gerne bananen dazu auch einen apfel", 2, "ich mag brezen mit butter"), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE )
   ```

Comment: Here is a base R method `as.matrix(aggregate(X2~X1,  data.frame(a), function(x) paste(x,collapse="")))`

Answer (score 2):

An answer with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

a <- as.data.frame(a)
names(a) <- c('group', 'text')

a %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(text2 = paste(text, collapse = " ")) %>%
  as.matrix()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
a<-matrix(c(1,"ich esse", 1, "gerne bananen", 1, "dazu auch einen apfel", 2, "ich mag brezen", 2, "mit butter"), nrow=5, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE )
d<- as.data.table(a)
d[,str_c(V2,collapse=' '),by=V1]
#   V1                                           V1
#1:  1 ich esse gerne bananen dazu auch einen apfel
#2:  2                    ich mag brezen mit butter
```